# Setting target directory for gRPC classes generated by Quarkus Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, grpc, quarkus, grpc-java

Running `./gradlew quarkusGenerateCode` works well, however the generated sources fall under the `build` directory:

[image]

I wouldn't like to set this path as a Gradle SourcesSet, "Mark Directory As" Generated Sources Root in Intellij, and so on as it's under the build directory.

Is there a way to set the output dir to something such as `src/quarkus-generated-sources`? The Quarkus user guides and the gradle plugin documentation are not too informative regarding that subject.

There's the `build.gradle`, nothing much special about it

```
plugins {
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-grpc'
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify an alternative path for the built-in code generation mechanism.

The classes generated by Quarkus from your `*.proto` files may change quite often. If you run Quarkus in the development mode, they will be regenerated on each change (in the `*.proto` files). In such a set up this is an outcome of the build rather than a source, that's why I put it in `build`.

I think you could use [Gradle protobuf plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) to generate the java files. It has an option to specify the output directory. Don't forget to register `quarkus-grpc-protoc-plugin` similarly to [Maven protobuf plugin configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-getting-started#generating-java-files-from-proto-with-protobuf-maven-plugin).
The drawback of switching to it is that you won't be able to use the full power of the development mode when modifying the `*.proto` files.

Comment: What's the point of having generated source files in the build directory? I need them in my main source tree, to be extended and implemented.

Comment: You can extend and implement stuff from the build directory too. Your IDE should pick them up automatically, you may need to reimport the project when you generate them for the first time. Even if it doesn't work, just right-click on the generated directory and mark it as generated sources